# What word describes a person who wants to do things that no one attempted to do before?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe a person who wants to do things that no one attempted to do before? (All kinds of things, generally.)

It can be a noun or an adjective.

I can think of "experimentist" but it sounds too scientific to me.
And I think "adventurous" would be off-topic, but I can't be sure.

Example sentences:

> "S/he is original, creative and  ___.

or

> S/he is a(n) ___.

Comment: All kinds of things. Generally.

Comment: How about [riding a steam-powered rocket above the atmosflat to prove the earth is flat](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/speaking-of-science/wp/2017/11/21/this-man-is-about-to-launch-himself-in-his-homemade-rocket-to-prove-the-earth-is-flat/?utm_term=.c32a3220a2d5)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call someone who is the first to do something a [**pioneer**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pioneer).